# Can't write image data to path in my coding

Tags: laravel, image, save, laravel-8

Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException
Can't write image data to path (C:\xampp\htdocs\marini\laravel-ecommerce\storage\app/public/images/categories/vitamin.jpg)

public function store(CategoryRequest $request)
{
abort_if(Gate::denies('category_create'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

```
    $image = NULL;
    if ($request->hasFile('cover')) {
        $image = $this->uploadImage($request->name, $request->cover, 'categories', 268, 268);
        
    }
   

    Category::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'category_id' => $request->category_id,
        'cover' => $image,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('admin.categories.index')->with([
        'message' => 'success created !',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    ]);
}
```